# How to use application.css.scss for all controllers in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I would like to ask a question, I write all CSS code in app\assets\stylesheets\application.css.scss file. But only first controller can use that file.
When I link_to another controller, I can't use any CSS code.

Can I use only one application.css.scss for all controllers in my application? such at `background-color`, `margin`, `padding`

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development for more information from offical source

Answer (score 0):

This should already configure in new rails application which created by you.

You wants to use the css files in all the controller then initialize them into

/app/views/layout/application.html.erb

like below example:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "css1","css2"%>
```

otherwise with one single line

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following in your layout/application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

It is a good practice to keep your application.css.scss file clean and only include code that directly affects the layout/application.html.erb file.

As far as adding code for all controllers and all views etc., I would suggest you put your code into a common file 'custom.css.scss' under the assets/stylesheets folder. 
You can then add the following line in your application.css.scss file

```
 * = require custom
```